# How to invoke a function in child component based on Boolean value passed from Parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am displaying a button from child component to AppComponent(parent). Whenever the button is clicked I would like to invoke the '*showAlert()*' method if '*lastPage*' value is set to true. But it doesn't seem to work. Attached a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujhsrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%3AL3-L3,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html)

Is this a correct way to invoke a function from the child component? is there a different way to do it?

**app.component.html**

```
<app-child [lastPage]="lastpage"></app-child>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  lastpage = true;
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<button>Click me for Alert</button>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() lastPage?: boolean
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showAlert()
  }

  showAlert() {
    if (this.lastPage) {
      alert('Button Clicked from child');
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options for triggering that function. You can use the OnChanges Hook as others mentioned or you can use a getter and a setter.

However, I think you should trigger the alert from the parent component rather than the child. The child component should be as dumb as possible.

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<void>();

  onClick() {
    this.clicked.emit();
  }
}

export class ParentComponent {
  lastPage = true;

  showAlertIfLastPage() {
    if (this.lastPage) {
      alert('Button Clicked from child');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<app-child (clicked)="showAlertIfLastPage()"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngOnChange hook for catch the input change and where you can call your method
[enter link description here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Answer (score 2):

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
   lastpage = true;   // true or false
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<button (click)="showAlert()">Click me for Alert</button>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() lastPage?: boolean
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {    }

showAlert() {
if (this.lastPage == true) {
  alert('Button Clicked from child');
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to react to a change in an Input() in the component is via the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle.

The `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle admits a paramater of type `SimpleChanges`
SimpleChanges class is defined like this:

```
class SimpleChange {
  constructor(previousValue: any, currentValue: any, firstChange: boolean)
  previousValue: any
  currentValue: any
  firstChange: boolean
  isFirstChange(): boolean
}
```

So you can leverage this properties to find out what is the currentValue of your `Input()` and act accordingly in your code:

```
ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
  if(changes.lastPage.currentValue){
    this.showAlert()
  }
}
```

You can find more info in this page:
https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges